# Alter existing method to incorporate Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm attempting to convert the methods I've written to be thread-safe (when needed), but I'm not exactly sure where bottlenecks might be happen to require threading.

Here's a method I created to load a local CSV file into a dataTable, that is created dynamically based on the content in the CSV.

```
    private void CsvLoader()
    {
        var openCsv = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
            Filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };
        if (openCsv.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        if (!openCsv.CheckFileExists) return;
        var csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(openCsv.FileName), true);
        try
        {
            var columnCount = csv.FieldCount;
            var headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
            var adt = new DataTable();

            for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                adt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headers[i]));
            }
            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                var rowOfData = adt.NewRow();
                for (var number = 0; number < columnCount; number++)
                {
                    rowOfData[number] = csv[number];
                }
                adt.Rows.Add(rowOfData);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = adt;
            SunderCsv(adt);
        }
        catch (Exception xmlExc)
        {
            //exception logging
        }
    }
```

So for a method like this, I was under the impression that I need to create a thread, like so:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(someParameterHere?);
    t.Start();
```

Do I just wrap the whole method in a thread, or only loops / iterations? I'm just looking for some guidance, as I've just started working with threading.

Comment: You cannot call UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread. You'll have to refactor your methods to properly marshal calls to the UI. Your question is also extremely broad - threading is a very complex subject and you cannot just turn throw a function over to another thread unless it was implemented with that in mind: this includes canceling a thread, passing progress information, etc.

Comment: ah, so threading will essentially be entirely re-doing most of my methods then? I see. I'll look into it and see how to code with threading from the outset.

Comment: It's hard to answer that from your small snippet but if you generally have any UI logic in your functions, you will have a lot of work to do. First refactor your code to layers where your worker functions do not have any UI references to begin with (ignore threading just yet). You can start worrying about threads then. To be able to write reliable multithreaded code, you must have a very clear separation of tasks in your code.

Comment: In addition to what @xxbbcc has noted, there are *very* few (if any) good reasons to read from a single file in parallel.  For that matter, it's highly unlikely that your hardware won't serialize the requests to disk anyway.  Now, if you wanted to read from multiple CSVs at once, that would be a perfectly valid reason to parallelize.  But the use case presented by your code just isn't going to benefit much from parallelism.  (That, and writing to a DataTable in parallel isn't thread safe anyway!)